# How to download an audio file from internet and play it using AvAudioplayer in Iphone sdk?

Tags: objective-c

I need to download an audio file from the net and want to play it Using AVAudioPlayer.can any one give me suggestions how to do this.

Comment: Guy's Please give me a quick response Im so eagerly waiting for your response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the NSURLConnection if you save the file in the server. the following is the link:
http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSURLConnection/sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:

This is the method name `sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:`

For the playlist, I am not used before, so cannot help you.
Good luck.